# What is the root password in Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.04, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

I am trying to make Java and wireless access available to all the users and it asks for authentication, but my admin account's password doesn't go through. I'm assuming it's root, can anyone help me?