# Ubuntu Root user

Tags: root, sudo, accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

Hi folks, I have been getting hands on Ubuntu and really liking it. Though someone of the terms really confuse me. One such confusion is: "**Just remember, when sudo asks for a password, it needs YOUR USER password, and not the Root account password**". On my system I remember I just have one password and I never configured two passwords. So how do I find my Root account password?

Comment: Exact Duplicate: How to know my root password?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password