# Root Access in Natty

Tags: 11.04, root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

How to access root in Natty? usually, i use this methode for login as root `sudo password root` but in Natty this methode not work. there a solution?

Comment: You have a typo, it's passwd, not password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that you can install "nautilus-gksu" which will give you root access on the right click menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be root in a terminal it is `sudo su`.

Comment: no, I mean how to access folder in root. I want to try copy and paste into root folder. in maverick, I only login to root with method [sudo password root] and I can access folder in root

Comment: `sudo passwd root` (see Jorge Castro's post)

Comment: @robin0800 A more elegant way is `sudo -s`. See [the community documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells) for more details.

Comment: @EliahKagan And that should be the only fair answer!