# What is the difference between 'su -' , 'sudo bash' and 'sudo sh'?

Tags: command-line, bash, root

I would like to know what is the difference between

- `su -`
- `sudo bash`
- `sudo sh`

I cannot login as root while doing `su -` because I do not have the root password - I mean I have my user password with which I can `sudo "command"`  but this password does not work for `su -`
I can log in as root with `sudo bash` with my user password and I can login while doing `sudo sh` but then I get a command prompt in this form
`#`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Background**

In Linux (and Unix in general), there is a **SuperUser** named **Root**. The SuperUser can do anything and everything, and thus doing daily work as the SuperUser can be dangerous. You could type a command incorrectly and destroy the system. Ideally, you run as a user that has only the privileges needed for the task at hand. In some cases, this is necessarily Root, but most of the time it is a regular user.

**su -**

This command is used to login at root account.
By default, the Root account password is locked in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as Root directly or use the su command to become the Root user. However, since the Root account physically exists it is still possible to run programs with root-level privileges. This is where sudo comes in - it allows authorized users (normally "Administrative" users) to run certain programs as Root without having to know the root password.

See [**How to Enable Root Account**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling%20the%20root%20account).

**sudo sh**

This command runs "sh" as a super user.
The sh utility is a command language interpreter that shall execute commands read from a command line string, the standard input, or a specified file.

**sudo bash**

This command runs "bash" as a super user.
Bash is the shell, or command language interpreter. Bash is an sh-compatible shell that incorporates useful features from the Korn shell (ksh) and C shell (csh). It is intended to conform to the IEEE POSIX P1003.2/ISO 9945.2 Shell and Tools standard. It offers functional improvements over sh for both programming and interactive use. In addition, most sh scripts can be run by Bash without modification.

References: [1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo), [2](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sh.html), [3](http://www.gnu.org/s/bash/).

Comment: It's worth noting that you can log in as the super user by running ``sudo su -`` without a root password. Because sudo runs the ``su -`` command with root permissions, you will only be prompted for the user's password. This has the advantage of setting up the root user's environment, which may not be done by simply running a shell with sudo.

Comment: A good explanation of the env vars that change with these: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-i-vs-sudo-bash

Answer (score 6):

`su -`:

This will change your user identifier and inherit the environment variables as if you had logged in with that user.  Normally you would use the format `su - <userid>` to login as the user .  If you drop the "userid" it assumes you are trying to login as root - which you can't (unless you change the root password).

`sudo bash` & `sudo sh`:

Anything  after the sudo is a program to run - so in these cases you are asking to run a couple of shells - bash and dash respectively. use `man bash` and `man sh` for more details on the different shells.

---

Related Questions:

- [image: Ask Ubuntu] [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)
- [image: Stack Overflow] [What Linux shell should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199661/what-linux-shell-should-i-use)

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply but what is the default password for root then ? Where can I find it ?

Comment: @lordmonkey root doesn't have a password, and doesn't need one. `sudo -i` will give you a login shell like `su -` would, except sudo asks for your password, not root's.