# I dont know what does sudo su bash mean

Tags: 13.10

I want to run `amun honeypot` on Ubuntu 13.10 and I sometimes have problem with running this honeypot. I just write this command `$ sudo ./amun_server.py &` but it cant work sometimes. I want to try this command `sudo su bash` but I don't know what this command can do.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between 'su -' , 'sudo bash' and 'sudo sh'?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57040/what-is-the-difference-between-su-sudo-bash-and-sudo-sh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you type:

```
 sudo <command>
```

you are running  as **root** user, the requested password is your password. Only your **uid** is changed and the environment is the same as your user.

When you type:

```
 su
```

**[su](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/su.1.html)** command without parameter allow user to become superuser. In this case the requested password is about root.

When you type:

```
 sudo su
```

you are running **su** as **root** user, **[sudo](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/sudo.8.html)** ask your password and su does not. So you can become root without knowing the password.

**Caution: It is strongly recommended to not use this command unless you really know very well what you are doing**

If you want exec command as another user login shell environment:

```
 sudo su - <user> -c <command>
```

or

```
 sudo -u <user> -i <command>
```

Here is useful [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/341980/running-a-program-as-another-user-without-typing-a-password/502222#502222)

Comment: Hi Letizia it was so usefull thannks for your answer

Comment: @ Shahrzad Torabi zadeh if this is what you are looking for, update your question as requested and clarify what you need. This will help other people that have same problem to find out more easly information they need.

Answer (score 3):

Hi Why not open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `man su`? That will explain what the `su` command does.

Similarly with bash.

man = manual and it gives a list of arguments that can be used with the command.