# How to access root acount?

Tags: 10.10

I'd installed `Ubuntu 10.10` inside `Windows 7`.

At the time of installation it didn't asked for any `root` account but when I'm trying to install `DB2` it want access to `root` account.

How can I go to `root` account in `terminal` of `ubuntu 10.10`?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo "Just remember, when sudo asks for a password, it needs YOUR USER password, and not the Root account password."

Comment: @arrange: beside of my own account there is always a `root` account. How can I access it?

Comment: 1. Please please read the link. 2. What do you mean by *accessing* here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know my root password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Terminal**
Try `sudo su` and enter your password. This will allow you to start apps as root and do administrator tasks.

**GUI**
Start a program with `gksu` to give ir root privileges. Press Alt+F2 and write `gksu <application name>`

Comment: Why would you recommend running sudo su? That's usually a bad idea. It's much better to use sudo for each command.

Comment: Maybe because the question was "How can I go to root account in terminal"?

Comment: This probably isn't ideal, you want either `sudo -i` or `sudo -s`

Answer (score 1):

We don't use a password for the root account in Ubuntu. Instead, you prepend the command with sudo, so that instead of `/etc/init.d/someservice start`, you'll run `sudo /etc/init.d/someservice start`. There are many benefits to this approach. First of all, you don't have to be root all the time, but instead run single commands as root. That also means each command gets logged and that different users can run root commands without sharing a password. It also enables you to fine-tune access. You can enable a user to run a specific command as root without giving complete access to the root account.

Comment: Isn't there any problem as I'd installed `ubuntu 10.10` inside `windows 7`?  
I think some of the software or services requires `root` account to do a task. Isn't it?

Comment: The root account is used. You just can't login as root. If you use <code>sudo apt-get install blah</code>, then <code>apt-get install</code> is run as root, but you'll use your own password. So, in a company, for instance, you might allow a web administrator to run <code>/etc/init.d/apache</code> as root, but nothing else. This is a great benefit of using sudo.