# What's the regular way to add an admin user?

Tags: server, cloud, users, administration

I have installed an Ubuntu server cloud version on my AWS instance. Anyway the default user name is specified as `ubuntu`, and i don't like it. Because I have my own policy for admin account name. So I'll create a new admin account to manage whole server.

How can I add *admin* user? There's a utility for adding normal user, but it's not applicable for admin users.

Comment: Possibly the same question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer . There is not an admin user on Ubuntu, there is an admin group. So, you can add your new user to this group easily.

Comment: Root is always there if you want: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sudo adduser username admin` will make "username" an admin user.