# How to become root?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

I have been trying for a week and a half trying to become root so I can change the motd for an assignment and I have had no luck.  Can someone break it down into linux for dummies style please. I have done every update for ubuntu 12.04 do not know if this why it is giving me a hard time?  Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a duplicate.  The linked post is a problem related to a 3rd party application not expecting Ubuntu's security policy, whereas this one seems to rather just be the user not understanding Ubuntu's security policy.  Still a well documented problem(non-problem) but probably not a duplicate of that specific link in my opinion.

Comment: Not a duplicate whatsoever

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend trying it through command line.

First, open up terminal. Then enter this command `sudo su` and press enter. It will prompt for your password. After entering the password, everything that you are doing WITHIN THE TERMINAL is being done as you as root. I emphasized that to show that anything you do outside of the terminal will NOT be root.

So, to edit the motd, type this into terminal: `gedit /etc/motd` and edit your file accordingly.

Comment: `sudo -i` works too instead of `sudo su`. That said, it is not a very good idea to be root in an interactive shell for small jobs like these.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use root privileges, you need to use `sudo`, and your user has to belong to the sudo group.

to find out if you're user is a member of the sudo group, you can just run the `groups` command:

```
nathwill@ragnarok:~$ groups
nathwill adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirtd
```

Then, to run a single command "as root", you just do `sudo command arg`

To assume root privileges indefinitely, or "sign in as root", you can use `sudo -i` to obtain a root prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's security policy does not allow anyone to become root (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=716201)).

Instead preface every command with `sudo` and then use your password to gain root privileges for that command.

**SUDO Examples**:

Copy a file to a directory owned by root:

```
sudo cp ~/example.txt /etc/example.txt
```

instead of

```
cp ~/example.txt /etc/example.txt
```

To change the privileges of a file owned by root:

```
sudo chmod 775 example.file
```

instead of

```
chmod 775 example.file
```

You don't actually ever need to become root; you can always use sudo to preface commands that require root privileges.

For applications that have a GUI, use `gksudo`.

**GKSUDO Examples**:

To edit a text file owned by root:

```
gksudo gedit example.txt
```

instead of

```
gedit example.txt
```

If your want to browse/copy/paste/etc. files using a GUI you can run

```
gksudo nautilus
```

instead of

```
nautilus
```

All of these commands can be entered into a terminal, or, if you'd prefer to not use a terminal, you can just press `alt-F2` and enter the commands there.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can turn your terminal into a root session by typing su or you can prefix a command with

```
sudo <command>
```

to run that particular command as a superuser/root

To edit motd, the command is

```
 sudo nano /etc/motd.tail
```

nano is a terminal text editor.

If you want to use a graphical interface just swap nano out for gedit.

Comment: If you want to use gedit you should swap gksudo for sudo as well.  ie. gksudo gedit /etc/motd.tail

Comment: @adempewolff Why? `sudo` seems to work fine even with GUI apps.