# Logging in as root

Tags: login, password

Newbee to Ubuntu.
I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04.
How do I log in as root? Alternatively, when performing su, what's the default root password?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here in ubuntu su can is been replaced by sudo which will automatically deroot you after closing the terminal

Comment: Assuming your goal is to run commands as root (not specifically to log in or su as root), you should [use `sudo`, as explained in this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). So this may be a duplicate of [How do I run a command as root?](http://askubuntu.com/q/371027) ([the answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/371030)) or [How to become root?](http://askubuntu.com/q/140361). See also [What are the benefits of sudo over su?](http://askubuntu.com/q/135428), [this general question](http://askubuntu.com/q/245201), and [this one about running GUI apps as root](http://askubuntu.com/q/270006).

Answer (score 1):

root, as a user, has a disabled password for your protection.  To run a program as root, use either `sudo` or `gksudo`, if the program is terminal based or graphic based.  For example, to edit your rc.local file, you would open a terminal and type `gksudo nano /etc/rc.local`

The password for performing items with the root permissions is the same password you logged on with.

There are methods for enabling "root" as a user - if you have a need for this, you will find the appropriate links.