# permission denied for root@localhost for ssh connection

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and LAMP on that. Then, I wanted to configure my server, so tried out [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-12-04) tutorial.

When I give the command:

```
ssh root@localhost
```

I get : Permission denied, please try again.
I have logged in as root user through the command :

```
sudo -i
```

I also tried the same, by logging in through:

```
sudo -s
```

I use the same password as that I used to log in as user, but still am getting the same error message.

Could someone help me out here?

PS: I looked into [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171521/what-is-the-password-for-ssh-rootlocalhost) but didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

By default, the SSH server denies password-based login for root. In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, if the following line exists, possibly commented out (with a `#` in front):

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Then change it to the following, uncommenting if needed (remove the `#` in front):

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And restart SSH:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Or, you can use SSH keys. If you don't have one, create one using `ssh-keygen` (stick to the default for the key, and skip the password if you feel like it). Then do `sudo -s` (or whatever your preferred method of becoming root is), and add an SSH key to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`:

```
cat /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: I get this error: cat: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory .

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I assumed you had an SSH key. As your user, do `ssh-keygen` (skip a password for the SSH key if you wish, and stick to the defaults for the rest) to create one. Also, I hope you replaced `user` with your actual username.

Comment: Both the methods didn't work for me! I even checked my home folder; it's empty. What should I do?

Comment: @muru Maybe you can just mention that they need to remove the `#` at the beginning of the line in the config file to un-comment the line for anyone else who may not know

Comment: This might [help](https://askubuntu.com/a/449372/321926) to get a feeling for `without-password`.

Comment: In Kali Linux's sshd_config, there's a line of "PasswordAuthentication no" need to change to yes before it can accept ssh root@ip access. I was blocked by that for several days before I figured that out.

Answer (score 8):

In some cases, after change,

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

must check this config:

```
DenyUsers root
AllowUsers saeid
```

and to enable login must change to:

```
#DenyUsers root
AllowUsers root OtherUser
```

Answer (score 4):

If u have not given password for root and you are trying to fire command on spark or haddop like `./sbin/stop-all.sh or./sbin/start-all.sh` . If you don't have a root password, you can setup one using

```
sudo passwd
```

and fire commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this. I needed **two PCs**, **one on Ubuntu and another on Arch**, to sync files through Unison but ran into the same permission denied error. Just for the sake of those who are having the same problem as I was, here's what I did:

First: Installed the same version of Unison on both PCs. This was a bit challenging as the one available on the software center was behind to what was readily available for Arch. So, I couldn't find a higher version for Ubuntu, so I replaced the one on Arch with a lower one instead. Found one here: http://zdia.de/downloads/unison-2.40.102-linux-x86_64. The same version is in the software center for Ubuntu.

Second: Followed the steps from here:
https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-unison-file-synchronization-between-two-servers-on-debian-squeeze
(Note: Arch was my server 1 and Ubuntu was my server 2.)

I ran into a problem in step 3 as I tried to ssh-copy. But it was resolved by changing "id_dsa.pub" into "id_rsa.pub" in the "ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_dsa.pub root@192.168.0.101" line. Probably my fault, as I think I forgot to add "-t dsa". Anyway, try the original command first. **IF** you get an error, **then** change to rsa.

After following the steps above, I found I still couldn't get Unison to connect to the other server, neither can I log in (without Unison) through ssh to the other server. Finally,after hours of google searching, I was led to this page, and the answer given my Muru sealed the deal.

After applying it, I could now login via SSH to server 2.

So I ran Unison, and corrected the profile settings, and viola!

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR and like to code in `sed` to circumvent `permission denied` in `ssh`

```
sed -i s/#\(PermitRootLogin*\).*/\1 yes/ /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Comment: And `service ssh (re)start`

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with qemu login.
One of the issues could be that `authorized_keys` on the remote machine does not match with the host machine's key from where you are trying to login.

Copying the `id_rsa.pub` from host to `authorized_keys` of the remote PC should help.