# Can't SSH in as root

Tags: server, ssh, password, authentication

I'm using the default installation of `openssh-server` for my Ubuntu 14.04 server. I can connect through the console as root like normal, with my username and password. When I try to SSH with the same username/password, however, I repeatedly get Access Denied errors. `/var/log/auth.log` reports `Failed password for root from <ip address> port <port> ssh2`, but I'm entering the correct password.

Why can't I connect to the server via SSH, even though the username and password ARE correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [need to connect as \*\*root@my-server-ip\*\* with SSH](http://askubuntu.com/questions/511922/need-to-connect-as-rootmy-server-ip-with-ssh)

Comment: @EliahKagan He he, I had reported that as dupe of this before it had got an answer. :D

Comment: @muru I think either way would be okay, but [that one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/511922/need-to-connect-as-rootmy-server-ip-with-ssh) seems a little broader in sccope (more general), has more answers, and has answers suggesting a wider range of solutions. Either way they're closed, answers from one could be mod-merged into the other (or not).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable ssh root access on Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/469143/how-to-enable-ssh-root-access-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: If your server is in anyway outward facing please don't enable SSH as root. This is asking for trouble.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [permission denied for root@localhost for ssh connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/497895/permission-denied-for-rootlocalhost-for-ssh-connection)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

The default setting in Debian (and hence Ubuntu) for OpenSSH Server is to deny password-based login for root and allow only key-based login. Change this line in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And restart the SSH server:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Aha, that did it! Thank you, I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @Vaindil But really, as [gregory.0xf0 says](http://askubuntu.com/a/511926/22949), if you must log in remotely as root, it's much better to [use key-based instead of password-based authentication](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).

Comment: @Vaindil I second EliahKagan and gregory.0xf0 that key-based authentication is superior to password based. Switch to it if you can.

Comment: It is, by the way, bad practice to allow root login anyways via SSH or via the GUI, you should only ever need root login in cases where `sudo` is disabled.

Comment: If it still not working, please try setting password for the root. For me that helps: `sudo passwd root`

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with the posts above: it would be better to login in to a user account once with password to do a ssh-copy-id to set up keys.  Then use ssh to the user account followed by sudo.  If you really want to login as root, you should set up keys.

Comment: You might need to uncomment the line, by removing the `#`, if needed.

Comment: This is decidedly weird: one of my other top answers is essentially this, posted a month before this one: https://askubuntu.com/a/497898/158442 I guess they were so similar, I never remembered I had two different posts for the same thing.

Comment: Why oh why do they logs not show this at all? Neither SSHD log nor auth.log mention that, the falsely claim that the password is not correct. This is super important, logs need to show a reason for a failure CLEARLY and unambiguously.

Answer (score 7):

To me, works changing (Ubuntu 18.04):

- `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

---

- `PermitRootLogin prohibit-password` to `PermitRootLogin yes`
- `PasswordAuthentication no` to `PasswordAuthentication yes`

---

then, restart ssh service:

- `sudo service ssh restart`

Thanks!

Comment: you can add to your answer: some default installations require changing root password for ssh as root directly, as is the case of Kali Rpi.

Answer (score 2):

Hackers will bang away with root user trying to brute force their way in.  If you are going to allow root logins, you should definitely install Fail2Ban, or something similar to protect against brute force attacks.  Also use a very hard to guess password without the use of common words.

And, as Vaindil pointed out, a key based login would be far superior. They are not very hard to setup.  Here's a link to setup key-based login using PuTTY on windows: https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/use-ssh-keys-with-putty-on-windows/ .  But there are lots of others if you are using a different environment to login from.