# need to connect as **root@my-server-ip** with SSH

Tags: ssh, root, vps

I have a VPS with Ubuntu 14.04. I need to login as root to my server over SSH.

I set a password for root: `sudo passwd root`
then enabled it: `sudo passwd -u root`
then rebooted my vps: `sudo reboot`

But I still can't connect with the root user. How can i enable ssh login as **root**?

Comment: Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to see if root login is allowed.

Comment: On my server I disabled root login, but gave my user sudo access. So I login with my account, then `sudo su` when I need root.

Comment: @MichaelOzeryansky i can use `su or sudo -i` but i need to use `ssh root@my-ip`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 i check it, but still i can't login as **root**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default on Ubuntu 14.04 in /etc/ssh/sshd_config is

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

which forbids root logins using password authentication.  This is a good idea because brute-force login attempts against the root user are extremely common.

To login as root, I recommend setting up [key-based SSH login](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys).  Another (dangerous!) possibility is to change the option to `PermitRootLogin yes`.

Comment: I add `PermitRootLogin yes` and restart ssh service. but ican't connet with `root@ip`. it returns `Access Denied`

Comment: @user2517728 I have to wonder: If you're still having problems after following this answer's instructions, how is this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question directly, but if your intent is simply to administer your machine remotely, it is generally considered preferable and safer to log in as a non-root user, then elevate your privileges once you have started a session on the server.

In other words, instead of using ssh root@yourserver, you may wish to log in as yourself (your own distinct username and account) then run `sudo bash` or even `su` and to authenticate as root once logged in.   You can also prepend most commands with `sudo` to have that command run with root's privilege level, e.g.,:

`sudo cp /etc/configthing.conf /etc/configthing.conf.orig` or

`sudo rm -i /var/log/syslog.3.gz`

Comment: @belacqua This answer is suggesting to SSH in as a non-root user and then use `sudo` or `su` to elevate to root. This is the preferred way to administer a system remotely via SSH (including on OSes were the root account is enabled by default). I don't think the OP said they tried this--instead, they said they'd run the `passwd` command with `sudo`. While the alternative presented here arguably does not match the OP's parameters, this may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), and the disadvantages of allowing remote root logins are enough that we should probably keep this.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on having to log in as root, I'd suggest logging in as a normal user, running

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

and then (without closing that session), trying to log in as root via SSH and observe the authentication error messages appearing in the first session.

You should be able to figure out the reason you're unable to log in as root from there, otherwise posting /etc/ssh/sshd_config might get you an answer more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many examples online so I will not repeat them.

The one thing they do not say is you need:

```
ssh-add [path_to_key]
```

when using a custom name (not default) for the key.

If you insist on only using a password not a public-private key pair:

```
ssh root@server-ip-or-hostname
```

and type your pass.