# SSH into Ubuntu server (14.04.1) Using mac terminal (os version 10.9.4)?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I am having difficulty connecting remotely to the ubuntu server from the mac terminal.

So far I have run:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

when I try to connect via the ip address I get an error:

```
$ ssh root@*ip address*
ssh: connect to host *ip address* port 22: Connection refused.
```

How do I go about resolving this? Thanks in advance for your help

Note: I am not actually typing *ip address*. I'm just using this in place of my actual server ip address

Comment: Are you sure the ssh daemon is running on the ubuntu server?  What is the output of this command?  `sudo netstat -pant | grep ssh`

Comment: tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      9288/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      9288/sshd

Comment: Looks like the server is listening; might be a firewall issue then.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Any insight on how I could go about resolving this?

Comment: Are you authenticating with keys? I believe that the default sshd_config for Trusty sets `PermitRootLogin without-password` (meaning you won't be able to login as root using password-based authentication - that's assuming you have even enabled the root account of course).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I enabled the root account via:http://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login. I am  new to Ubuntu, so any further help would be appreciated. I am getting this error:   WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!...

Comment: Just enabling the root user is not enough. As steeldriver has said, you net to enable it in the SSH configuration as well: http://askubuntu.com/questions/511833/cant-ssh-in-as-root/511836#511836. That said, a connection refused error is not an effect of that. Can you ping the Ubuntu server from the osx system?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the Ubuntu server.

Comment: Also, I have already done: http://askubuntu.com/questions/511833/cant-ssh-in-as-root/511836#5118 The error: " WARNING: REMOTE HOST..." is the error I am getting even after enabling root account.

Answer (score 0):

First try to `ssh` into the server with another user besides "root".  Root remote connection is disabled by default.  Or you can allow remote access with root.
You will need to edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, and comment out the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password
```

Just below it, add the following line:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then restart SSH:

```
service ssh restart
```

Another suggestion would be to ensure that the firewall was turned off on the VM before proceeding with the network adapter changes. Some O/S versions default with the firewall turned on which may block incoming SSH connection attempts. After turning off iptables or ufw depending on your O/S version or whichever service you are using. IF this doesn't resolve the issue, then try each network adapter setting within VirtualBox.

```
sudo ufw disable
```

or

```
sudo service iptables stop
```