# Ubuntu 16.04 ssh connection permission denied error

Tags: ssh

We are unable to solve the below error in Ubuntu16.04:

```
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

We have tried [this Ubuntu Handbook guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/enable-ssh-ubuntu-16-04-lts/).

What else can we try?

Comment: actually there is no /root/.ssh file to regenerate the key

Comment: my system is able to connect all other systems but my system is not connecting to any other system..I installed a fresh Ubuntu16.04LTS version systm today

Comment: Now, maybe you enable firewall in server, so you can disable firewall or allow port ssh in firewall with command: " sudo ufw disabe " or " sudo ufw allow from any  to any port 22 "

Comment: We have tried both the commands, but remains same error: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: Its worked for me by followed the below link:https://askubuntu.com/questions/497895/permission-denied-for-rootlocalhost-for-ssh-connection

Answer (score 0):

Follows the below steps:
By default, the SSH server denies password-based login for root. In /etc/ssh/sshd_config, change:

PermitRootLogin without-password

to

PermitRootLogin yes

And restart SSH:

sudo service ssh restart