# How to set up passwordless ssh for root account?

Tags: ssh, password, root

i am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to set up passwordless ssh between root accounts (needed to use Ambari).

However this involves `ssh-copy-id user@machine` and since user is root, when I try to do this: `ssh-copy-id root@mypc` I get asked for root's password. AFAIK there is no password, but please correct me if I am wrong, and any other pointers are gratefully received.

EDIT: so what I am trying to do is ' 'install your public key in a remote machine's authorized_keys ', but won't I always need to use the root password for this, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yes, sorry I put the wrong link in, edited now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171521/what-is-the-password-for-ssh-rootlocalhost) question may provide an answer. I need to "log in as root using sudo -s then use passwd command to set root password."

SOLUTION: I used sudo su - root and passwd which worked.However this lead to a permission denied error when trying `ssh -l root slave3` , subject of a new [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/791266/trying-to-ssh-root-why-get-permssion-denied-in-16-04).

Answer (score 1):

On the remote machine type

```
sudo passwd
```

This will allow you to set the root password on the remote pc.

You can then type on your local machine

```
ssh-copy-id root@remotepc
```

After which you will be prompted with a password prompt where you will enter the password you created earlier.

From then on when you type

```
ssh root@remotepc
```

You will not be prompted for a password.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh-copy-id` is not magic!

```
# where is ssh-copy-id?
$ type -p ssh-copy-id
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id
# What is ssh-copy-id?
$ file $( !! )
file $( type -p ssh-copy-id )
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Next, you need to read `ssh-copy-id`, find out what `ssh-copy-id` does, and find alternate ways to accomplish the same tasks. If a shell script can do it, you can, too!

Comment: OK it is used to 'install your public key in a remote machine's authorized_keys ', but won't I always need to use the root password?