# Trying to ssh root, why get permssion denied in 16.04?

Tags: permissions, 16.04, ssh, root

I'm trying to set up passwordless ssh between root accounts in 16.04 (needed for Hadoop installs).
I set up a password for root by `sudo su - root` and `passwd`.

When I try e.g.

`ssh -l root slave3` or `ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_root.pub  root@master`

I get

`Permission denied, please try again.`

I have tried all the advice I can find i.e. making the following edits (one at a time) to /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
PermitRootLogin without-password 
PermitRootLogin yes 
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#StrictModes yes
UsePAM no
AllowUsers root hduser
```

Followed by `sudo service ssh reload` after each, but still I get permission denied. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you run `ufw` or any other firewall on any of the machines? Then make sure port 22 is open for in and out communication.

Comment: I don't think so, how do I check 22 is open, I'm pretty new to this stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the default SSH policy is "Deny root login via SSH directly, except by SSH Key Authentication only."  This is done by the `PermitRootLogin without-password` line of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

You can enable root password login over SSH by changing that line to say `PermitRootLogin yes`.  However I must caution you - this permits brute forcing attempts over the Internet of the `root` password which puts your server at risk - you may wish to consider blocking all SSH traffic except from known "good IP sources" of which you trust the source IPs in order to reduce the chance of being brute-forced on the root login.  Where this is not possible, you should strongly consider setting up SSH key authentication for the root account instead of password authentication.

Comment: Thanks but I tried both those things and still get permission denied.

Comment: Did you comment out the `without-password` line or leave it in uncommented?  (looking back at the edits you said you did)

Comment: Ah that was the problem, I commented out the without-password line and it let me login. Still not sure how I set up password less root though! Thanks for your help, much appreciated!!

Comment: @user1773592 Use the `ssh-copy-id` command again.  Alternatively, copy your public key by hand into `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server and then try and logon again.  If the ssh works without password prompt then you are good to uncomment the `without-password` line and comment out the `yes` line and all should then work.

Comment: With 'yes' ssh-copy-id worked fine but the logon asks for a password and then logs in OK.  With 'without-password' (or with neither) I get permission denied.