# How do I get the root account?

Tags: root

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know my root password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password)

I want to get "root" account and I want to be root!

But this 12.04 used a tile @ start screen. Unlike the older one using type account, tile not type, and it is the weakness! so I can't find "root".

Please help me to root this my Ubuntu.