# What is meant by "no password set" for root account (and otthers)?

Tags: password, sudo, encryption, root

Several years back, we were more accustomed to changing to the root account using the `su` command. First, we switched to the root account, and then executed those root commands. Now we are more accustomed to using the `sudo` command.

But we know that the root account is there. We can readily find the home directory of user root.

```
$ ls -ld /root/
drwx------ 18 root root 4096 Oct 22 17:21 /root/
```

Now my point is, it is stated that "the root password in Ubuntu is left unset". Please see the answers to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-do-i-recover-my-root-password). Most of the answers
have something to this effect in the first paragraph. One or two answers further state that "the account is left disabled".

Now my (primary) questions are,

1. What is meant by an unset password? Is it blank? Is it null? Or something else more cryptic?
2. How does the account becomes enabled once I set password for it? (`sudo password root`)

In order get a better understanding, I checked the `/etc/shadow` file. Since I have already set a password for the root account, I can no longer see what is there (encrypted password). So, I created another account and left it disabled. The corresponding entry in the `/etc/shadow` file is,

```
testpassword:!:16020:0:99999:7:::
```

Now perhaps my above queries need to be changed to, what does an `!` in password field mean? Other encrypted passwords are those very long cryptic strings. How come this encrypted form is only one character long? And does an account become disabled if I put an `!` in
the (encrypted) password field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is meant by an unset password? Is it blank? Is it null? Or something else more cryptic?

Is just inexistent. Root account is disabled by default, hence it doesn't need password. So, what most resemblance has is `undefined` (in JavaScript) or `(null)` (other languages). It is just unset.

> How does the account becomes enabled once I set password for it?

Actually, setting the password is just part of it, but doesn't enable the account. You need to enable the account using:

```
sudo usermod -U root
```

and then set the password with `passwd`.

> what does an `!` in password field mean?

Extracted from `man shadow`:

> > A password field which **starts with a exclamation mark** means that
> >                the password is locked. The remaining characters on the line
> >                represent the password field before the password was locked.

It could mean that the account is locked. But also:

> > If the password field contains some string that is not a valid
> >                result of crypt(3), **for instance `!` or `*`**, the user will not be able
> >                to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the
> >                system by other means).

Either way, any account with `!` can't log in with applications that use the shadow file.

> How come this encrypted form is only one character long?

Is not encrypted. See above.

> And does an account become disabled if I put an ! in the (encrypted) password field?

See above too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm learning about that as well as it's a new topic for me. From what I understand the account exists but is not enabled, so trying to use it just keeps on responding that the credentials are wrong. It appears to be to make it harder for malicious users to know why they can't crack the password. If you already have it set I would highly suggest that you undo it with:

```
    sudo passwd -dl root
```

and to learn more about it go to:

```
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo
```

Comment: This is good information, but try to find specific answers to the 2 parts of the question that the OP mentions. :)