# "Permission denied, please try again." ERROR when trying to connect to localhost through ssh

Tags: permissions, ssh, password

I know this problem has been discussed several times in the forum but none of the steps recommended to remedy the problem have worked in my case.

In the following I will describe again the problem and then explain the (unsuccessful) measures I have taken so far to remedy the error.

I tried to check the functionality of my ssh server by connecting to it via the following command. After typing in the correct password, I am presented with this message:

```
$ ssh root@localhost
root@localhost's password: 
"Permission denied, please try again."
```

To remedy the problem I made the following change to the `sshd_config` file:
I set:

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

Then I restarted the SSH Server again by giving the command:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

However, when trying to connect to the server I got the same response as before:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I checked `/etc/shadow` and saw that there is an exclamation mark in front of the root user password (i.e. the password is locked).
To unlock it I gave the command:

```
$ sudo usermod -U root
unlocking the user's password would result in a passwordless account.
You should set a password with usermod -p to unlock this user's password."
```

Hence, I gave the following command :

```
sudo usermod -p root
```

But the exclamation mark in front of the root password is still there and I still can't connect to the SSH server ... Is there anybody who knows what the solution to this problem is?

Comment: I myself pointed out that this question has been asked before, but the problem is: the answers to these questions did not solve the problem in my case (although I tried all the steps recommended ... see the description of the measures I have taken)

Comment: have you set a password for root? `sudo passwd`?

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip ... I typed in the command "sudo passwd" ... then I "updated" my password  (My "new" password is the same as the "old" one though) .... Then I tried to connect to the ssh server again ... and this time it worked! ... I do not understand why it worked though. I had a password for sudo before (which I had to type in before I could type in my "new" password) ... Why did "updating" my password make it possible to connect to the ssh server?

Comment: Because the password `sudo` is your account's password, not the root accounts. When you did `sudo passwd`, you set root's password.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-find-out-root-password-for-installing-software

Comment: I see ... that explains everything.  Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For the sake of security you may want to limit ssh access to root account. If you must have it, then I would add `AllowUsers root@192.168.1.*` in /etc/sshd_config so you can only connect to root from local network. Or you can assign an exact ip  to allow from