# How to get root password after installing ubuntu

Tags: 13.04

Same as title can't get root password I've tried suddenly passed root won't let me

Comment: Why do you need to get root password? There is no root password in Ubuntu and also 13.04 release is no longer supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out root password for installing software](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-find-out-root-password-for-installing-software)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the root account password is **locked** in Ubuntu. This means that you cannot login as root directly or use the su command to become the root user. Nevertheless, you are able to enable root password by the command:

```
sudo passwd
```

---

## NOTE

Enabling the root account is rarely necessary. Almost everything you need to do as administrator of an Ubuntu system can be done via `sudo` or `gksudo`. If you really need a persistent root login, the best alternative is to simulate a root login shell using the command `sudo -i`.