# Can't log into root user in terminal, keys don't work in GRUB

Tags: grub2, root

When trying to install things I'm told that I have to log in root user (which I'm supposed to be already), I try and I'm told that my root password is incorrect. I try to reset it and when I get to the GRUB my arrow keys won't work. I tried checking the BIOS to see if there's a problem with my USB settings, but there weren't.

Comment: To "install things", one temporarily becomes `root` using the `sudo` command, and supplying one's login password. See `man sudo`. Ubuntu tries to avoid `root` logins.

Comment: Make sure to connect malfunctioning USB-things (your keyboard) without ANYTHING (i.e. hub) between the thing and the computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out root password for installing software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-find-out-root-password-for-installing-software)