#  sudo, su problems

Tags: 10.04, sudo, su

During the installation process I was asked to set a password. I chose a password (a strong one) and everything goes smoothly every time I log in. Problems arise whenever I resort to "sudo" or "su" commands ...

I mean, if I type "sudo or "su" I'm compelled to provide a password and whenever I type 
the password I choose during the installation process I get this error:

```
Authentication failure
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the error comes from the way you use sudo.

Sudo should be used by your regular (non-root) user the following way:

```
sudo command
```

When prompted for a password, you should enter your user's password or in other words, the password used at login.

Answer (score -3):

This is known from Ubuntu, you did not set root password.

the password you have set is your user's password and has no relation to the root.

please take a look at this link and see if it can help : http://www.debuntu.org/recover-root-password-single-user-mode-and-grub

P.S : I left ubuntu for good just because of these lame *features*, I'm a developer and I need to function with everything, why limit me -.-

Comment: Sudo prompts for your current user password, not the root password. It's perfectly safe to run an Ubuntu installation as it's intended to be run: without a root password set. [It's for security purposes](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1360/what-is-the-root-password-in-ubuntu). That being said you can always [set the root password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9017/how-to-know-my-root-password) at anytime.